# Differenet Errors while running maven project with existing pom.xml to netbeans

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, pom.xml

this is my first project using Spring (and I'm not too experienced with Maven either)
I tried to import a new maven project with existing pom.xml  to netbeans.
I saw a lot of questions asked here before but the answers didn't fix these errors.

`mvn clean install` return this error

> [INFO] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [ERROR] 
>   Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin
>   :1.2.0.RELEASE:repackage (default) on project ssh-on-web: Execution default of g
>   oal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.2.0.RELEASE:repackage fa
>   iled: Unable to find main class -> [Help 1]

Also when i try to run the maven web-application with tomcat it returns this error :

> Undeploying ...
>   undeploy?path=/
>   OK - Application non déployée pour le chemin de contexte /
>   In-place deployment at C:\Users\admin\Desktop\ssh-on-web-master\target\ssh-on-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT
>   Deployment is in progress...
>   deploy?config=file%3A%2FC%3A%2FUsers%2Fadmin%2FAppData%2FLocal%2FTemp%2Fcontext6208589662765502295.xml&path=/
>   ECHEC - Application déployée pour le chemin de contexte / mais le démarrage du contexte a échoué

here you find how the pom.xml looks like :
    pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <packaging>war</packaging>

        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
            <relativePath/>
            <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>

        <groupId>ssh-on-web</groupId>
        <artifactId>ssh-on-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

        <properties>
            <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
            <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        </properties>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.hierynomus</groupId>
                <artifactId>sshj</artifactId>
                <version>0.11.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.sf.expectit</groupId>
                <artifactId>expectit-core</artifactId>
                <version>0.6.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.4</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
            <mainClass>com.kodcu.ApplicationStarter</mainClass>
            <layout>ZIP</layout>
            <goal> run </goal>
          </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>


    </project>
```

and this is how my project directories looks like : 
[My web-application tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxQag.jpg)

Best regards

Comment: i think you got an error in declaration in the parent of dependency `org.springframework.boot` : take a look to [this](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-1.3.3.RELEASE.pom)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I found out later that I had put `pom.xml` in the wrong directory. I had put it in: `src/main/java/`. The correct location for `pom.xml` is in the `src` folder, at the same level with the `main` folder.

If you made the same error, just put it in the right folder in `src`, and then run `mvn clean install` again, and it'll run just fine.